# delete has_many through relationship Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many, destroy

I'ved got a Ruby on Rails app

I have Block that has_many Unit that has_many User through user_unit_assocs.
The model is define as such.

```
class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :block
  has_many :users, :through => :user_unit_assocs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_unit_assocs, dependent: :destroy

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units, :through => :user_unit_assocs
  has_many :user_unit_assocs, dependent: :destroy
```

The problem is when I delete Block
- unit gets deleted
- user_unit_assoc gets deleted
- BUT the user of the unit DOES NOT GET DELETED

How do I solve this problem to make sure it cascade block to user as well. Problem is the through but I cant change now the table structure, how can I solve these dependent records deletion properly. Thanks.

Comment: I guess `has_many :users, :through => :user_unit_assocs, dependent: :destroy` should be actually a `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: Where is the user_unit_assoc model?